# how to rename uploaded file?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

I made a form in ASP.NET with VB background code.
my problem is I want to make that the file which is been uploaded to by the form
to change to "Resemey.doc" instead for example "012 MaraCSD.doc"

did a bit of research and found out I need to add some code to my vb code.
but couldn't find what, and where to put it.

this is my code:

```
'Add the namespace for the email-related classes
Imports System.Net.Mail

Partial Class SendAttachment    
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page   

    Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        'Make sure a file has been uploaded

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(AttachmentFile.FileName) OrElse AttachmentFile.PostedFile Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ApplicationException("לא העלאת קבצים.")
        End If

        if AttachmentFile.PostedFile.ContentLength >600000 then   
          'display error file size should be less than 100kb   
        end if


        '!!! UPDATE THIS VALUE TO YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS
        Const ToAddress As String = "pelleg@gmail.co.il"
        dim textMsg as String
       textMsg ="שאלות סינון" &
 (vbCrLf)  & (vbCrLf)  & (vbCrLf)  & question1.text & (vbCrLf)  & q1.text & 
(vbCrLf) & (vbCrLf) & question2.text & (vbCrLf) & q2.text & 
(vbCrLf) & (vbCrLf) & question3.text & (vbCrLf) &q3.text & 
(vbCrLf) & (vbCrLf) & "ממליצים" & (vbCrLf) & c1.text & (Space(5)) & c2.text & (Space(5)) & c3.text & (vbCrLf) &
 (vbCrLf) & question4.text & (vbCrLf) & q5.text & (vbCrLf) &
 (vbCrLf) & "פרטים אישיים" & (vbCrLf) & 
(vbCrLf) & "שם מלא" & (vbCrLf) & pi1.text & (vbCrLf) &
 (vbCrLf) & "כתובת מייל" & (vbCrLf) & UsersEmail.Text & (vbCrLf) &
 (vbCrLf) & "טלפון" & (vbCrLf) & pi2.text & (vbCrLf) & 
(vbCrLf) &"שעות נוחות" & (vbCrLf) & pi3.text & (vbCrLf) & 
(vbCrLf) & (vbCrLf) & "הערות"  & 
(vbCrLf)  & body.text & (vbCrLf) & 
(vbCrLf) & "מעוניין בהצעות נוספות" & (vbCrLf) & q4.text 
 '  

        '(1) Create the MailMessage instance
        Dim mm As New MailMessage(UsersEmail.Text, ToAddress)

        '(2) Assign the MailMessage's properties
        mm.Subject = Subject.text &  "-" & pi1.text
        mm.Body = textMsg

        mm.IsBodyHtml = false

        'Attach the file
        mm.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(AttachmentFile.PostedFile.InputStream, AttachmentFile.FileName))
        mm.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(AttachmentFile2.PostedFile.InputStream, AttachmentFile2.FileName))

        '(3) Create the SmtpClient object
        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient

        '(4) Send the MailMessage (will use the Web.config settings)
        smtp.Send(mm)

        'Show the EmailSentForm Panel and hide the EmailForm Panel
        EmailSentForm.Visible = True
        EmailForm.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            'On the first page load, hide the EmailSentForm Panel
            EmailSentForm.Visible = False

        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

any ideas?

Comment: I would refer to the System.IO.File::Move() method.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx

Comment: what doesn't work?  Do you have some example code and details on any exceptions that are thrown.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the SaveAs method of the PostedFile and save it as whatever name you want..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.saveas.aspx